# How can I change the response code of an http request using middleware?

Tags: go, go-chi

I'm trying to develop an api gateway using go-chi. I want that if request includes "_always200=true" in query, I will set status code to 200.
Here what I tried:
**custom_response_writer.go**:

```golang
type CustomResponseWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    Buf         *bytes.Buffer
    StatusCode  int
    WroteHeader bool
}

func NewCustomResponseWriter(w http.ResponseWriter) *CustomResponseWriter {
    return &CustomResponseWriter{ResponseWriter: w, Buf: new(bytes.Buffer)}
}

func (c *CustomResponseWriter) WriteHeader(code int) {
    c.StatusCode = code
    c.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(code)
}

func (c *CustomResponseWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return c.Buf.Write(b)
}
```

**middleware:**

```golang
func HeaderFilterMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        always200, _ := r.Context().Value(always200QueryKey).(bool)
        crw := NewCustomResponseWriter(w)
        next.ServeHTTP(crw, r)

        if always200 {
            crw.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        }
    })
}
```

It is always returns 404. Is there any way to fix that ?

Comment: Not seeing the rest of your code, my only guess as to why it is always 404 is because you didn't setup your route correctly.

Have you added something approximately like: `r.Use(HeaderFilterMiddleware); r.Get("/hello", routeHandler)` when creating your mux?

Comment: Sure, I add it before routing.
`router.Use(middlewares.HeaderFilterMiddleware)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two issues in the code.

1. `always200, _ := r.Context().Value(always200QueryKey).(bool)` is not the  correct way to get the query parameter. I think you should read it with `r.URL.Query().Get("_always200")` and compare the value to the string `"true"`.
2. it's too late to call `crw.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)` after `next.ServeHTTP(crw, r)`. It printed this warning message when I tested the code:

   ```
   http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from main.(*CustomResponseWriter).WriteHeader
   ```

Here is an amended example that changes the status code of a response:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "net/http"
    "strings"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
)

type CustomResponseWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    Buf                *bytes.Buffer
    OriginalStatusCode int
    WroteHeader        bool
    always200          bool
}

func NewCustomResponseWriter(w http.ResponseWriter, always200 bool) *CustomResponseWriter {
    return &CustomResponseWriter{
        ResponseWriter: w,
        Buf:            new(bytes.Buffer),
        always200:      always200,
    }
}

func (c *CustomResponseWriter) WriteHeader(code int) {
    c.OriginalStatusCode = code

    if c.always200 {
        code = http.StatusOK
    }
    c.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(code)
}

func (c *CustomResponseWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return c.Buf.Write(b)
}

func HeaderFilterMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        always200 := r.URL.Query().Get("_always200")
        crw := NewCustomResponseWriter(w, strings.EqualFold(always200, "true"))
        next.ServeHTTP(crw, r)
    })
}

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.Use(HeaderFilterMiddleware)

    r.Get("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("welcome"))
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)
}
```

Comment: Yeah I didn't share my other codes. I'm getting query as shown as you but then I'm setting it in context. That's why I read it in this middleware. I'm nexting before, because I want to change the status code after everything is finished. But I will try this